# How to connect a Text View with a UITextField outlet , in iOS?

Tags: ios, textview, customization, textfield, outlet

I have a problem that really drives me crazy.

A few months ago i started developing an iphone application , and i needed to have a multiline textField so that the user could write some comments. In the end , because at the time i couldnt find a solution , i found a solution how to use a Text View instead which is by default multiline. In my project it seems that i have connected this Text View with a UITextField outlet.

Now i am trying to make my app universal , so i created a new .xib file for the iPad version.

However it seems impossible to connect the Text View that i created with the UITextField Outlet that i was using with the iphone .xib.

I m really breaking my head here to remember how on earth i connected these two in the first place. I remember that i implemented some delegate methods to customize the Text View to work as a Text Field , and it seems that all the properties of my iPad Text View are the same with the ones of the iPhone version. However i cant connect it with the outlet.

Does anyone have any idea , what i am missing here?

Comment: I don't think you can `UITextField` outlet to a `UITextView`

Comment: Man its really there! I see the Text View of the iphone .xib file connected to a UITextField Outlet from the ¨Show the connections inspector!¨ Even when , i am in the assistant editor and watch side by side the .xib with the .h and i put my cursor on the connection area of the outlet , the Text View becomes blue!

Comment: I don't think it is the case, you should show the screenshot, it might help us to see what exactly is happening there, you might have named your `UITextView` as `UITextView *textField` or something

Comment: no it is not possible.

Comment: see my answer to see what i did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that after all is possible..

I tried the unthinkable and it worked..

I created a new outlet from my text View , a UITextView outlet and then... well i just renamed the UITextView to UITextField and works perfectly.. I connected both textViews (iPhone.xib and iPad.xib) in this outlet and it works.. (I connected them before renaming it to a UITextField outlet cause after that you cant connect them)

Comment: and don't tell me that delegate methods are working only by doing this what you did???

Comment: yeah everything works great. The textView works exactly like a multiline textField.

Comment: well i don't think it is happening exactly, you are only changing the field type after connecting it does not mean it will change the behavior of its delegate methods

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. All i wanted was having a textView work like a textField. This is what i just did. The textView now behaves EXACTLY like a textField. You have a keyboard when clicking on it , you dismiss it , the text is stored in the outlet , everything works like a textField. Of course i used some delegate methods and customize things to do that , but the final step was to connect the textView to the textField outlet to accomplish it. I just couldnt remember how the hell i connected it. That was the way.

Comment: @d0nparalias You to realize that you didn't have to try to trick Xcode in order to do this. UITextFieldDelegate and UITextViewDelegate both exist.

Comment: Of course. But thats the way i did it for the iPhone and i was just curious what the hell was i doing and made it work at the time. Now i understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is imposible connect `UITextView` to `UITextField`. There is no solution or tweak using which you can alter `UITextView` to behave like `UITextField`. You better use some third party library and use it in your project. I am still surprised how you did it in your iPhone project. Can you please share some code how you did in iPhone for better understanding of what you are asking.

Comment: Man its really there! I see the Text View of the iphone .xib file connected to a UITextField Outlet from the ¨Show the connections inspector!¨ Even when , i am in the assistant editor and watch side by side the .xib with the .h and i put my cursor on the connection area of the outlet , the Text View becomes blue!

Comment: This is not possible. Please share some screen shot so that it will be helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Outlets can be connected to the same types only and they are pointing to the object of the same types and they have `1-to-1` relationship, you can not connect one outlet to multiple objects either.

You might have named your `UITextView` as `UITextView *textField`  or something , you need to Connect your `UITextField` outlet to the corresponding textField in your classes, you can not connect `UITextField` to `UITextView`.

Comment: see my answer please to see what i did